# A level 2022 Biology percentage increase question

Tags: zoology, homework, conservation-biology

[image: Q&A table]

[image: bar graph]

In January 2022 WBI12/01 they asked:

> 9c. In 1963, there were only three males and 12 females of
> C. hoodensis left in the wild.  These 15 tortoises were used in a
> breeding programme.
>
> ii.The wild population of C. hoodensis is now 1800 individuals.
> Calculate the percentage increase in the wild population of
> C. hoodensis tortoises.  Give your answer to one decimal place.

I did the calculation `1800-15`
(new-original value)
Then divided the difference by 15 (the original value) times 100 and got 11900.0%
But the mark scheme says

`1800-15 = 1785`

`(1785÷1800)x100% = 99.2%`

So I don't understand why they divided by the new value 1800, not the old one 15, since this was a percentage increase calculation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, in addition to being a ["homework"question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) — see link for an explanation and expectations, it is not primarily about biology as defined in the [help]. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Answer (score 4):

15 to 1800 is a `11,900% increase` (= form **A**)

or

`12,000% of the initial 15` (= form **B**).

They asked you for a percent increase, so they want the answer in (**A**) form.

The correct working:

Take the new value `1800`, divide by the original `15`, and multiply by `100` to get a percentage: `(1800/15)*100=12000` and thus you have a *percentage* answer in form (**B**). From this, to get form (**A**), subtract 100 at the end to get a percentage *increase*: `((1800/15)*100)-100=11900`.

You have to remember to distinguish forms **A** and **B**. To illustrate, 100% of 10 is 10, and 11 is a 10% increase from 10 (form **A**), but it is 110% of 10 (form **B**).

In other words... the marking scheme is woefully wrong. It claims the correct percentage increase in the wild population is 99.2%. That means it's below 100% *increase* (i.e. below doubling). **A 100% increase from a starting 15 tortoises means there would be 30 tortoises. Not 1800. So the mark scheme is hilariously incorrect.**